# Getting an error that values are out of range in the 'Buy Til' You Die' Package in R

Tags: r, package, warnings

Upon executing the following command in the BTYD package in R:

```
params <- bgnbd.EstimateParameters(cal.cbs)
```

Wherein cal.cbs is the following formula:

```
cal.cbs <- dc.BuildCBSFromCBTAndDates(cal.cbt, cal.cbs.dates,
                                  per="week")
```

I receive the following error:
Error in optim(logparams, bgnbd.eLL, cal.cbs = cal.cbs, max.param.value = max.param.value,  : 
  L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'

And the following warning: In beta.ratio(a + 1, b + x - 1, a, b) : value out of range in 'lgamma'

The picture in [Dataset sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBFLn.png) shows some values of the dataset used. Does anyone have any experience with BTYD that could shine some light on this issue? This is my first time using the package. If more information is needed please feel free to ask.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Tried a couple of changes from other users on this forum. The only one that worked is changing`tot.cbt <- dc.CreateFreqCBT(df)` to `tot.cbt <- dc.CreateFreqCBT(df.cal)` Keeping this question and relevant answer for future users coming across the same problem.